# Wordpress custom url rewrite

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

Is it possible in wordpress to rewrite the following url.

http://www.example.com/aboutus/?city=newyork to http://www.example.com/aboutus/newyork

and then read out the get_query_var('city') , how do i accomplish this within wordpress?

Comment: Have you set correctly your **permalinks** in *Settings* > *Permalinks*?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you explain yourself a little bit more. According to me the scenario above is very hard to achieve within wordpress. I can do city/newyork but i want to remove city from the url and still be able to read get_query_car('city') , what i want to achieve is create different content for each city in the usa for example

Comment: have you looked already to the [rewriting API of wordpress (codex)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API), in particular with `add_rewrite_tag()` and `add_rewrite_rule()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sollution:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
$vars[] = "city";
return $vars;
}

//https://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/
function eg_add_rewrite_rules() {
global $wp_rewrite;

$new_rules = array(
        'aboutus/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?page_id=274&city=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
);
$wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'eg_add_rewrite_rules' );


echo get_query_var('city');
```